# How to make a chat application in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I have build chat UI for my application using react-native-gifted-chat. I have connected the sent messages and received messages with the services. Can anyone help me with the issue of messages not getting updated instantly as the message is received?

Do I need to hit services again and again to refresh the chat message? if yes then how?

Or do I need to implement some kind of push notification? if yes then how?

I just want to make my chat screen update the message instantly when current user receives a message from another user.

Comment: most of the services would have a onMessage function

Comment: Can you please provide a link or any example if possible? thanks.

Comment: Sure. Take Sendbird as an example https://docs.sendbird.com/javascript/group_channel#3_receive_messages_through_a_channel_event_handler

Comment: Can you provide something regarding react native?

Comment: It can be used in a RN project.

Comment: https://github.com/sendbird/SendBird-JavaScript/tree/master/react-native-redux-sample

Comment: Follow this link : https://blog.jscrambler.com/build-a-chat-app-with-firebase-and-react-native/ with firebase

Answer (score 0):

Well, for update the message instantly when current user receives a message from another user you need to use firebase realtime database. it provides you to live data instantly..(for more info refer this tutorial **[https://medium.com/@*platypus*/react-native-chat-application-679dbff3ccd3](https://medium.com/@_platypus_/react-native-chat-application-679dbff3ccd3)**)

and for other option Socket.io also provides live data and it is better than firebase realtime database.